# How to access a variable in a function set provider outside its function flutter

Tags: flutter, provider

There is a list of items, I want to add them in favorites and display the favorites items in another page.

### items_list.dart

```
onPressed: () {
 Provider.of<MyAppProvider>(context, listen: false).addItems(items);},
```

### my_provider.dart

```
class MyAppProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
      List<items> selectedItems = [];

   void addItems(Items items) {
     selectedItems.add(items);
     notifyListeners();
   }

   List<Items> getSelectedItems() {
     return selectedItems;
   }
  }
```

### favorites.dart

```
Class favorites extends StatelessWidget {
 const favorites({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Items> favoriteList = Provider.of<MyAppProvider>(context, listen:false).getSelectedItems();
   print(favoriteList);
}}
```

When I try to print the favoriteList, it returns [] null. This happens when I refresh and goes to Favorites page

Comment: The list item refers to `FitnessAppProvider` but favorites to `MyAppProvider`. These are two different providers. You need to use the same one

Comment: @Ivo sorry, that was by mistake wrote another name. I have edited the question. I am using MyAppProvide

Comment: Did you check that the items are truly added?

Comment: @LeandroGonzálezCuello items are getting added, but then when I refresh the page and goes to favorites.dart it returns []

Answer (score 1):

You want to rebuild the listeners upon changing data in the provider and as @Ivo pointed out, you are using two different providers in your files.

**favorites.dart** should like like this:

```
Class favorites extends StatelessWidget {
 const favorites({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Items> favoriteList = Provider.of<FitnessAppProvider>(context).getSelectedItems();
   print(favoriteList);
}}
```

By writing `listen: false` you are indicating to the widget that it should not rebuild on changes or subscribe to the provider. This is often the case in a callback function but not in the widgets that are displaying that data and want to stay up to date.

Comment: I added ```listen:true``` still returns []

Comment: In that case there must be something else going on. Did you wrap your material app (or any higher level widget) in a ChangeNotifierProvider or a MultiProvider?

Also: Check if the values are added in your provider add() method. You could print the list after the add operation and see what's displayed.